# Integrate with Simpson's Rule in Python recursively

Tags: python, numpy, numerical-methods

I want to use Python to implement Simpson Integration. It's not hard if I don't need it converge (Here I need `abs(result - my_expect) < 0.001`) automatically.
But I want a automatic-converged Program written in Python. So I tried to use the method I learned from *SICP* -- to make it recursively.

```
# imports
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np

# constants
MU = 50
SIGMA = 15
X0 = 0
XN = 100


# interface functions
def f(x):
    """Integrand.

    It will be used for Lagrangian interpolation and
    calculating corresponding function value in function
    `improve_precision`.

    """
    y = (1 / (SIGMA * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi))
         * np.exp(-1/2 * (x-MU)**2 / SIGMA**2))
    return y


# classes
class Integration:
    def __init__(self, start, end):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        self.a = (self.end - self.start) / 2
        self.h = 2 * self.a
        self.rp = 0
        self.s = 0
        self.i = 1

    def integrate(self):
        return self.integrate_iter(1, 0, 0.001)

    def integrate_iter(self, expectation, summation, accuracy):
        if accuracy > abs(summation - expectation):
            return summation
        else:
            self.integrate_iter(expectation,
                                self.improve_precision(self.i+1), 
                                accuracy)

    def improve_precision(self, ii):
        rc = np.sum([f(-self.a - self.h/2 + k*self.h)
                     for k in range(1, 2**ii + 1)])
        self.s = self.h/6 * (self.rp + 4*rc)
        self.h /= 2
        self.rp = self.rp + 2*rc
        return self.s

calc = Integration(X0, XN)
print calc.integrate()
```

When I ran it, a lot of errors raised:

```
  File "/Users/*/integrate.py", line 72, in <module>
    print calc.integrate()
  File "/Users/*/integrate.py", line 56, in integrate
    return self.integrate_iter(1, 0, 0.001)
  File "/Users/*/integrate.py", line 62, in integrate_iter
    self.integrate_iter(expectation, self.improve_precision(self.i+1), accuracy)
  File "/Users/*/integrate.py", line 62, in integrate_iter
    self.integrate_iter(expectation, self.improve_precision(self.i+1), accuracy)
  ...
  File "/Users/*/integrate.py", line 65, in improve_precision
    rc = np.sum([f(-self.a - self.h/2 + k*self.h) for k in range(1, 2**ii + 1)])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 1708, in sum
    if isinstance(a, _gentype):
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
Process finished with exit code 1
```

So what should I do? Is there any way to make it correct?

### Edit:

Well, I made a change on function `integrate_iter` and added a function `is_rough`. My final code goes like this:

```
...
    def integrate(self):
        """A function encapsulate calculating process."""
        integrate_value = self.integrate_iter(0)
        interval_count = self.i
        return integrate_value, interval_count

    def integrate_iter(self, summation):
        """Main part of recursive process."""
        last_summation = summation
        summation = self.improve_precision(self.i)
        return self.is_good(summation, last_summation)

    def is_good(self, summ, last_summ):
        # if precision < 0.001, over; else, call `integrate_iter` again.
        if abs(summ - last_summ) <= self.accuracy:
            return summ
        else:
            self.i += 1
            return self.integrate_iter(summ)
...
calc = Integration(X0, XN, 0.001)
val = calc.integrate()
scipy_result = scipy.integrate.quad(f, X0, XN, epsabs=0.001)[0]
print 'The integration is: {0:.8f}'.format(val[0])
print 'The error is: {0:.8f}'.format(abs(val[0] - scipy_result))
print 'The number of recursions is: {0:d}'.format(val[1])
print 'The number of intervals is: {0:d}'.format(2**val[1])
```

I'm not quite satisfied with the number of recursion, I don't know whether it should converge so slow(according to my experience).

Comment: show us the full traceback.  that's not "a lot of errors."  it's the traceback for one error.

Comment: @dbliss I'd like to. But the traceback is too long. But the body limit of this question is 30000 characters. What should I do?

Comment: what is the value for `my_expect`?  knowing what you want the output to be would help us find an answer that works for you.

Comment: @dbliss It's 1. Sorry I didn't clarify it but I used it in this statement: `return self.integrate_iter(1, 0, 0.001)`

Comment: ^ ah, my bad, missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two fixes are needed inside `integrate_iter`.

First, when you increment `i`, you need to not only add 1 to `i`, but redefine `i` as `i + 1`.

Second, in your posted code, `integrate_iter` returns `None` when the `else` block is executed.  This prevents the improved result from being obtained within `integrate`, where it is needed so that it can be returned in the `print` statement.

```
def integrate_iter(self, expectation, summation, accuracy):
    if accuracy > abs(summation - expectation):
        return summation
    else:
        self.i += 1
        return self.integrate_iter(expectation,
                                   self.improve_precision(self.i), 
                                   accuracy)
```

Although the above works, I think it's clearer to write it this way:

```
def integrate_iter(self, expectation, summation, accuracy):
    if accuracy <= abs(summation - expectation):
        self.i += 1
        # Improve summation.
        summation = self.integrate_iter(expectation,
                                        self.improve_precision(self.i), 
                                        accuracy)
    # Summation is good enough; return.
    return summation
```

Comment: Yes, I did find that `integrate_iter` returns `None` after I posted it, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You missed out the main line from the stacktrace:

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Your recursive `integrate_iter` does not terminate.

Comment: Yeah, it's true. What should I do to modify it?

Comment: @nix is i supposed to be incremented at each stage in the recursion (because it's not being incremented)... would that fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Unless this is a learning exercise, you should use [scipy.integrate.quad](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html) instead --- it does adaptive integration in a more advanced way.